# Should each of my modules reference my MVVM Framework?

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

My solution/project structure is something like this

```
- MyApp.App
- MyApp.Domain             // everything that's shared between projects
                           // in one assembly for simplicity 
- MyApp.Modules.ModuleA
- MyApp.Modules.ModuleB
- MyApp.Modules.ModuleC
```

`MyApp.App` has access to the framework and wires up the *shell* and so on...

My Modules are just Views, Models and ViewModels. But when I use Caliburn Micro - for example - I have to inherit from base classes which are defined in the framework. Or to use attached properties in my Views.
That seems odd to me. So my question actually is: Isn't this some kind of anti-pattern? ViewModels shouldn't take care of the infrastructure, right?

Answer (score 0):

IN MVC/MVVM frameworks, the idea is to ensure that you separate the "type" of code between the V, M, and C (VM) layers.

[image]

**Example of What Not To Do**

For example, there was a company that wanted to transform an application coded in VS C# into a browser version (website) with ColdFusion so the multiple users could use it online without installing anything. However, we discovered that in their view layer there was a heavy portion of their business logic, that they didn't use interfaces but pure inheritance, heavy in coupling, and other things that would make the code entangled.

If they didn't have those issues, we could have moved most of the stuff into dlls and just focus on the view portion in Coldfusion using those dlls for the rest.

**Useful References**

Read the book Clean Code by Robert C. Martin. It has great arguments and ideas about coding.

Check out the philosophy behind S.O.L.I.D.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID

Check out Test Driver Development: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development

**Personal Opinion**

Frameworks are great. They contain useful libraries, imposed a standard for programmers to follow, and normally comes with may examples; however, you risk to be dependent of the framework.

For example, the iOS framework and the Android framework do things differently and they use a different language. Unless you are using a solution that converts your code into either framework, you are stuck.

In my case, in the old days, I had to maintain iOS and Android for a certain application. My approach was to have my business logic and model use interfaces and adapters when interacting with the framework.

[image]

- Regardless the language (Java or iOS) the business logic was the same = less work.
- The use of interfaces made it easier. I made myself a language converter and use it only on the business logic and interfaces. Since the business logic and interfaces didn't use objects or variables unique to the framework and language, it was easy to do the conversion.
- The adapters made sure that the communication between the business logic and the framework was the same. The business logic didn't care that the framework was Android and used CounterDownTimer or if it was iOS and used NSTimer. The business logic only knows about the interface ITimer which was use when connecting to TimerAdapter.